# $P(|X|\ge\lambda a)\ge (1-\lambda)^2a^2$ for $0\le \lambda \le 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

If $E(X^2)=1$ and $E(|X|)\ge a >0$, then $P(|X|\ge\lambda a)\ge (1-\lambda)^2a^2$ for $0\le \lambda \le 1$.

I can see from the well known inequality $E(|X|) \le E(|X|^2)^{1/2}$ that it must be the case that $a\le 1$. But what to do next I'm not sure.

Comment: I added some tags to your question. If you don't like that, please feel free to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$a\le E(|X|)=E(|X|\cdot 1_{|X|< \lambda a})+E(|X|\cdot 1_{|X|\ge \lambda a})\le \lambda a +E(|X|\cdot 1_{|X|\ge \lambda a}).\tag{1}$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and noting that $E(X^2)=1$, we have

$$E(|X|\cdot 1_{|X|\ge \lambda a})\le \big(E(X^2)\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \big(E(1_{|X|\ge \lambda a})\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\big(P(|X|\ge \lambda a)\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, the conclusion follows.